# Working tabs in dart

Tags: user-interface, tabs, dart

Are there any existing widgets/controls for displaying tabs in dart?

I have tried http://dart-lang.github.io/widget.dart/ , but atleast in my browser that example does not work even on that page.

I have also tried following http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/02/dart-widgets-blog-post-webcast.html to no avail.

Are there any other alternatives? Or any working guide how to use Dart Widgets?

Answer (score 0):

A simple tab control from Polymer UI Elements
https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements/tree/master/lib/polymer_ui_tabs

I'm currently working on porting Bootstrap tabs to AngularDart (will be available soon - about 1 week)
https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui

Comment: Thanks! I actually had seen that to but it does not seem to work either (http://erikgrimes.github.io/polymer_elements/build_ui/polymer_ui_tabs.html)

I'll guess i have to wait for one week or do my own :)

Comment: It may be that it needs a revision. The CSS selectors for ShadowDOM have changed recently and Dartium does support them only since a few days.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's the disadvantage of being at the forefront :) Thanks for the help, i will probably use some other page structure for the time being.

Comment: @MartinE I won't be able to finish the Angular UI Tab control this week. I have it on the agenda for next week.

Comment: Thank you for the consideration, i've decided on another layout for the time being and will probably not go back and change it for this project. But thanks anyway :)